# Record Center Resources

Tags: records-management, records-center

I am looking at using the Record Center site collection type in an upcoming project. What resources would you recommend to learn Record Center and what it can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsnoiwb/archive/2009/11/05/sharepoint-2010-records-management.aspx

[Records Management Resource Center](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff598594.aspx)